# java.io.IOException: write failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe) while take tcpdump from application process in android

Tags: tcpdump

trying to take tcpdump from application or from code.i am using following code

```
try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                "su");

        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(
                process.getOutputStream());
        os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
        os.writeBytes("/data/local/tcpdump-arm -c 10 -s 0 -w /data/local/out.txt\n");
        os.writeBytes("exit\n");
        os.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but getting exception java.io.IOException: write failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe) at os.writeBytes("/data/local/tcpdump-arm -c 10 -s 0 -w /data/local/out.txt\n");.Please help..

Answer (score 1):

EPIPE issue usually happens when you either try to execute command which needs root permissions (getRuntime().exec) in your case on the device without it or run several root commands simultaneously.